# JavaFX TableView Selection Binding doesn't always fire - is there a better work around?

Tags: binding, javafx-8

I have the need to disable a button in my application provided nothing is selected or multiple rows are selected.

I created the following binding (extra code to debug it since it wasn't working)..

```
BooleanBinding singleDocIsntSelected =
                Bindings.createBooleanBinding(() -> {
                    boolean result = documentTable.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems().size() != 1;
                    return result;
                }, documentTable.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty());
```

What happens to me is that when I select the first row, it fires, then if I CTRL + Click the same row, it fires again.  So far all is well in the world.  Then I Click the same row - nothing, or when I CTRL Click other rows nothing.

My button will stay in the wrong state.

However, if I also add a listener to the property:

```
ChangeListener<MyDTO> selectedItemsListener = (obs, ov, nv) -> {
    boolean result = table.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems().size() != 1;
    System.err.println(result);
};
```

Then everything works properly.

Is there no other way to handle this?

Comment: I tried that - same issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need the binding to be invalidated when the *list* of selected items changes, not when the `selectedItem` *property* changes. If one item is selected, that becomes the selected item: if you then select *additional* items, the `selectedItemProperty` will not change (it is still the first one selected out of all those selected).

Using your current idiom, just bind to the selected items list:

```
BooleanBinding singleDocIsntSelected =
    Bindings.createBooleanBinding(() -> {
        boolean result = documentTable.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems().size() != 1;
        return result;
    }, documentTable.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems());
```

or, more simply,

```
BooleanBinding singleDocIsntSelected =
    Bindings.createBooleanBinding(
        () -> documentTable.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems().size() != 1,
        documentTable.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems());
```

Though it's probably cleaner to use `Bindings.size()` and `IntegerBinding.isNotEqualTo()`:

```
BooleanBinding singleDocIsntSelected = Bindings
    .size(documentTable.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems())
    .isNotEqualTo(1);
```